# Laravel dont work method if i have 2 in 1 blade

Tags: laravel

I have 2 method in 1 blade, Delete and PUT, if i want delete it's work, but if I save info updated and I use method PUT, drop error: **The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT.**, I use form collective composer for form.

SAVE Button not working, drop error, Remove button working good.

Comment: You have to provide your code to understand what's wrong in it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pNNH4pi2

Comment: Provide your code _in the question_ please. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and please read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid mt--7">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            {!! Form::open(['action' => ['InvoiceController@update', $invoice->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="card bg-secondary shadow">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Edit {{$invoice->number}} invoice </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-right">
                            {{ Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
                            {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="pl-lg-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Company</label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="company_id" required>
                                             <option value="{{$invoice->company_id}}" selected>{{ $invoice->company_name->Name }}</option>
                                        @foreach($companys as $company)
                                            <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{ $company->Name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Payment</label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="payment" required>
                                        <option value="{{$invoice->payment}}" selected>{{$invoice->payment}}</option>
                                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                                        <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                                        <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Invoices number</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-alternative" type="text" value="{{$invoice->number}}" disabled>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="number" placeholder="Auto generated" type="text" value="{{$invoice->number}}" hidden>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Date</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-alternative datepicker-here" name="date" data-language='en' placeholder="Select date" type="text" value="{{$invoice->date}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Due date</label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-alternative datepicker-here" name="due_date" data-language='en' placeholder="Select date" type="text" value="{{$invoice->due_date}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="my-4" />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">No.</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    @if(count($invoice_lists) > 0)
                                        <?php $no = 1; ?>
                                        @foreach( $invoice_lists as $invoice_list )
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{ $no }}
                                                    <input type="text" name="list_id[]" value="{{ $invoice_list->id }}" hidden>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control form-control-alternative" type="text" name="description[]" value="{{$invoice_list->desc}}" placeholder="Description"></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control form-control-alternative qty" type="text" name="qty[]" value="{{$invoice_list->qty}}"  placeholder="Qty"></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control form-control-alternative price" type="text" name="price[]" value="{{$invoice_list->price}}"  placeholder="Price"></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control form-control-alternative amount" type="text" name="amount[]" value="{{$invoice_list->amount}}"  placeholder="Amount"></td>
                                                <td>
                                                   @if ($no == 1)
                                                        {!! Form::open(['action' => ['InvoiceController@remove', $invoice_list->id, $invoice->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                                                        {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                                                        {{ Form::submit('Remove', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', 'disabled']) }}
                                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                                    @else
                                                        {!! Form::open(['action' => ['InvoiceController@remove', $invoice_list->id, $invoice->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                                                        {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                                                        {{ Form::submit('Remove', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) }}
                                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                                    @endif
                                                </td>
                                                <?php $no++; ?>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @else
                                        ....
                                    @endif
                                    </tbody>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="2"></th>
                                            <th scope="col"><b>Sub Total</b></th>
                                            <th scope="col"><b>VAT(21%)</b></th>
                                            <th scope="col"><b>Grand Total</b></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="2"></th>
                                            <td scope="col">
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative sub" value="{{$invoice->sub}}" disabled>
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative subhidden" name="subhidden" value="{{$invoice->sub}}" hidden>
                                            </td>
                                            <td scope="col">
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative vat" value="{{$invoice->vat}}" disabled>
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative vathidden" name="vathidden" value="{{$invoice->vat}}" hidden>
                                            </td>
                                            <td scope="col">
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative grand" value="{{$invoice->grand}}" disabled>
                                                <input class="form-control form-control-alternative grandhidden" name="grandhidden" value="{{$invoice->grand}}" hidden>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="my-4" />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Terms and Conditions</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="terms" rows="5" placeholder="Terms and Conditinios" required>{{$invoice->terms}}</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="id" value="{{$invoice->id}}" hidden>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple forms in 1 form, this is not actually good idea, but if it is critically required to have so, you have to give unique id attribute to each form and also set form="currentFormId" to the form's inputs

Comment: Maybe you give examples for change